# Is a junk answer "spam" or "not an answer?"

Tags: support, flags, spam

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24430274/1234256), for example, is the following:

> ```
>                                                                                                                                                                                         hgfjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj
> ```
>
> hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
>   hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Should this be flagged as spam (Although it's not an advertisement), or not an answer (Although it's more urgent than something that really should've just been a comment)

Comment: Another option to throw out there is "offensive, abusive, or hate speech" - posting junk could be considered abusive.

Comment: You just got Darth Vader's account deleted.  Your ass is grass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an answer.

It's definitely not spam, but may well have the same result in that I (for one) would probably destroy the account posting this.

Comment: Sic 'em: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3779279/user3779279